# Is there any way to get more accurate speed using gps on android?

Tags: android

I'm using gps to calculate the speed

But sometimes I get incorrect values

For example, I keep walking at a speed of 4 km/h, but suddenly the value shows that I am walking at 10 km/h, and then the value of 4 km/h comes back to normal.

Is there any way to correct this value?

thank you

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 500, 0.0f, gpsListener);
```

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    if(lastLocation != null)
    {
        if(location.hasSpeed())
        {
            currentSpeed = location.getSpeed();
        } else {
            double deltaTime = (location.getTime() - lastLocation.getTime()) / 1000.0;
            currentSpeed = lastLocation.distanceTo(location) / deltaTime;
        }
    }
    lastLocation = location;
}
```